# Encryption/Decryption using ZipArchive class

Tags: .net, encryption, php-ziparchive

I did some investigation and cannot see native way to implement encryption/decryption using `ZipArchive` class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx

It seems like MSDN does not provide this posibility...

Am I right and if I am  not then how to encrypt/decrypt ZIP using `ZipArchive` class?

Thanks!

**P.S.** Is this approach a good one?
[Encrypt an existing zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795017/encrypt-an-existing-zip-file?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Do yo need standard zip encryption or special one?

Comment: @mkysoft The beter choice for me is  to use classes that Microsoft provides to manage ZIP. If it has standart ZIP encription than it will be enough. Thank you!

Comment: .Net framework doesn't support encryption in ziparchive. If you can't use third party library, you can only implement encryption class to standard which are given by @Hans

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can stop looking, Microsoft did not implement it.  Encrypting the file(s) yourself before adding them to the archive is an obvious workaround but doesn't exactly give the recipient a shot at decrypting them again.

You'll have to fall back to the kind of libraries that were popular before .NET got zip file support.  Lots to choose from, SharpZipLib and DotNetZip where the leading contenders.  Both support a password on the archive and allow you to control the encryption algorithm when you create the archive, important if you care about the weak Zip 2.0 algorithm.